# Not able to align text with image?

Tags: html, css

**Problem:** I would like to align the text with the image. Meaning, I would like to text to be in the middle.

```html
<div style="margin-top:0px">
    <p style="margin-top:2px">
        <img src="images/pdf-icon-24.png" alt="Dermatology_Referral_Guidelines" class="float-left" />
        <a href="Downloads/PhyDownloads/Dermatology_Referral_Guidelines.pdf" target="_blank">Dermatology Referral Guidelines</a>
    </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, please provide a running example that can demonstrate your problem and clarify what you're trying to do :)

Comment: What all did you try doing?

Answer (score 1):

Use `vertical-align: middle;` on the `<img>`.

*****Note this only works for a single line of text.***

```css
img {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<p>
  <img src="http://placehold.it/200x40/fc0">
  Some text here.
</p>

<p>
  <img src="http://placehold.it/200x40/fc0">
  Topsail broadside handsomely draught interloper aye killick prow lugsail execution dock. Man-of-war spike Sea Legs clap of thunder tender belay ho parley grapple heave to.
</p>
```

**Note:** I made the assumption that the text is supposed to be on the same row/line as the image and not below it. Meaning, aligned to the middle of the *y-axis* of the image and not the *x-axis* of the image.

Comment: @ hungerstar: Not seeing your results on my end

Comment: @RobertoFlores what results are you seeing? This solution works with the markup you provided in your post. Do you have other CSS on the page that could be interfering?